# Calling javascript function from another function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the `JsonObject` value in a function which is defined in another function, so I am using it like below.

```
function downloadPDF(e) {
setImagesUploadedFile(objValue); // another function
var obj = objValue[0].Filename;
var filePath = SharedFilePath + obj;
$('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', filePath);}
```

And that function `setImagesUploadedFile(objValue);` is here like this

```
function setImagesUploadedFile(JsonObject) {
for (i = 0; i < JsonObject.length; i++) {
    var obj = JsonObject[i].Filename;
    var obj2 = "ImgSignedDoc";
    var obj3 = JsonObject[i].FileType;
    var datafileName = JsonObject[0].ImageName;

    var ImgObj = parent.document.getElementById(obj2);
    var Filename = datafileName.substring(datafileName.lastIndexOf('//') + 1);
    ImgObj.innerText = Filename;
    $(ImgObj).attr("data-filename", Filename);
}
```

}

and the error it shows is

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'objValue' is undefined

So what should I do or change in order to get the parameteres of `setImagesUploadedFile(objValue)` in my another function ??

Comment: variable objValue is not defined in your downloadPDF function

Comment: What is objValue when you call it in the function downloadPDF? Did you assign it somewhere?

Comment: you are passing `setImagesUploadedFile(objValue);// objValue as argument but not defined`. What you want exactly?

Comment: @Hornet: I want to use the parameters of `JsonObject` in my `downloadPDF` function

Comment: Where is a value returned from `setImagesUploadedFile()` call?

Comment: @guest271314: I have not returned it right now.

Comment: Where is `objValue` defined? Are you trying to set `obj` to the result of `setImagesUploadedFile(objValue)`
`var obj = setImagesUploadedFile(objValue)[0].Filename;`? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: @VVVV: if you want to use the `objValue` in `downloadPDF ` function, you can pass this as argument like your way, but where you are getting the value of `objValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is before you even start: `objValue` is never declared and populated.

```
function downloadPDF(e) {
    // At this point objValue is undefined
    setImagesUploadedFile(objValue); // another function

    var obj = objValue[0].Filename;
    var filePath = SharedFilePath + obj;
    $('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', filePath);
}
```

Try using `'use strict'` declarations to better errors here as it will cause errors on the undeclared variable reference, rather than when it is used.

I think you're trying to treat `objValue` as a reference - that works for edits but not instantiation (JS has no `out` parameter), so use a return instead:

```
function downloadPDF(e) {
    'use strict';
    var json = // However you get your JSON data...
    var objValue = setImagesUploadedFile(json); 
    ...
```

Then, in `setImagesUploadedFile`:

```
function setImagesUploadedFile(jsonObject) {
    'use strict';
    var result = [];
    if(jsonObject) // Check we were passed the object
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
            ...
            var imgObj = ...

            // Add the result to the expected output array
            result.push(imgObj);
        }

    // Return the output array
    return result; 
}
```

So, steps to fix this:

- Add `'use strict';` to get better errors.
- Declare variables before you use them.
- Use `return` from a function to get values out.

Finally, as a side note, there's a convention in JS to use camelCase for functions and variables, and only use CapitalCase for classes and functions that expect to be called with `new`. You don't have to use it, but it can help make your code easier to understand.

Comment: so how is this an answer ??

Comment: i know the error part. what steps should I take to resolve this? Please suggest

Comment: @VVVV I'm guessing you commented on the first edit? Your fundamental problem is `objValue` is never declared and populated - I've fleshed out the answer with suggestions on how to fix that.

Comment: getting error as `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference`. I used your latest answer but getting error

Comment: now I get error as `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'JsonObject' is undefined`

Comment: @VVVV it the same issue - where is `JsonObject` declared?

Comment: it is declared on server side like this `var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objFile);
                string strscript = "setImagesUploadedFile(" + json + ")";`

Comment: @VVVV Ah, so injected inline by C# (or something like it)? That approach can be fairly painful to debug. You may be better off rendering an input, then reading that out, something like `setImagesUploadedFile(JSON.parse($('#jsonInput').val()))`

Comment: what is `#jsonInput` here and how shd I use it ?

Comment: @VVVV It would be a hidden input with the JSON content - are you using C#? Then it would be `<input type="hidden" value="@json" id="jsonInput" />` or `<input type="hidden" value="<%:json%>" id="jsonInput" />` depending on the view framework you're using. I've updated the answer with a check for undefined JSON content.

Comment: i m going in a meeting, will update you once i m back. bye for now

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadPDF(e) {
    // objValue is not declared, is this a global variable, if yes then declare it before calling the downloadPDF function.
    setImagesUploadedFile(objValue); // another function
    var obj = objValue[0].Filename;
    var filePath = SharedFilePath + obj;
    $('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', filePath);
}

var objValue = [];
downloadPDF(e);
```

or you can get the values of the objValue from where you want like:

```
var objValue = $("#id or class");
downloadPDF(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `objValue` before passing into  function.
Eg:

```
function downloadPDF(e)
{ 
    var objValue = {key1: value, key2: value};
    setImagesUploadedFile(objValue); // another function var obj = 
    objValue[0].Filename; var filePath = SharedFilePath + obj; 
    $('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', filePath);
}
```